# htpasswd wont access the site even with the right credentials

Tags: .htaccess, .htpasswd

Hi,

I have this in my htaccess

```
AuthUserFile /home/www/test/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "My restricted Area"
Require valid-user
```

this is my htpasswd file

```
test:$apr1$y38eqctj$LVKOW1ywu4vNE2PDDP3CT1
```

as I try to access the page I get the password prompt and even after I input the right credentials nothing happens and the site wont show. The page just stays there on Firefox whereas on Chrome the prompt just keeps popping up.

Whats wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: I believe its ngix

Comment: What do you mean you "believe its nginx"? You certainly should be aware what http server you yourself use or operate... And if that is "nginx" then please note that a ".htaccess" file and the contents you implemented there only make sense for an apache http server...